# 2 AjaxForm на одной странице MODX Revolution?

Tags: php, ajax, cms, modx

Версия MODX: **Revolution**

**Первая форма:**

```
[[!AjaxForm?
   &snippet=`FormIt`
   &form=`ajaxForm`
   &emailTpl=`email_tpl`
   &hooks=`FormItSaveForm,email`
   &emailSubject=`Заявка с сайта red-fox`
   &emailTo=`dance@red-fox.online`
   &emailFrom=`dance@red-fox.online`
   &validate=`name:required:minLength=^2^,tel:required`
   &validationErrorMessage=`В форме содержатся ошибки!`
   &successMessage=`Сообщение успешно отправлено`
   &emailFromName=`red-fox`]]

<form action="/" method="POST" class="">
        <h4>Записаться на бесплатную неделю занятий</h4>
        <span class="error_name"></span>
        <input type="text" class="input-text" placeholder="Ваше имя:" name="name" value="">
        <span class="error_tel"></span>
        <input type="tel" class="input-text tel" placeholder="Телефон:" name="tel" value="">
        <input type="submit" value="Записаться" class="input-btn">
        <span class="exit">
            <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
        </span>
</form>
```

**Вторая форма:**

```
[[!AjaxForm?
   &snippet=`FormIt`
   &form=`ajaxMassage`
   &emailTpl=`email_Massage`
   &hooks=`FormItSaveForm,email`
   &emailSubject=`Заявка с сайта red-fox`
   &emailTo=`dance@red-fox.online`
   &emailFrom=`dance@red-fox.online`
   &validate=`theme1:required,name1:required:minLength=^2^,tel1:required,text1:required`
   &validationErrorMessage=`В форме содержатся ошибки!`
   &successMessage=`Сообщение успешно отправлено`
   &emailFromName=`red-fox`]]

<form action="/" class="redfox-form" method="POST">
   <h1>Обращение в Red Fox</h1>
   <span class="error_theme1"></span>
   <input type="text" placeholder="Тема:" value="" name="theme1">
   <span class="error_name1"></span>
   <input type="text" placeholder="Ваше имя:" value="" name="name1">
   <span class="error_tel1"></span>
   <input type="text" placeholder="Ваш телефон:" value="" name="tel1" class="redfox-tel">
   <span class="error_text1"></span>
   <textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Сообщение:" name="text1"></textarea>
   <input type="submit" value="Отправить" class="red-fox__btn">
</form>
```

Первая форма работает нормально. При заполнении второй формы и нажатии на кнопку отправить появляется уведомление что данные отправились, но письмо на почту не приходит. В чем может быть проблема? хелп
Сайт red-fox.online (первая форма находится в футоре ссылка «записаться на пробное занятие», вторая форма на странице RedFox).

Answer (score 1):

AjaxForm есть просто обертка для Formit,рекомендую взглянуть на параметр &submitVar и задать уникальное имя для каждой кнопки. 
И имя одно у textarea оставьте

```
<textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Сообщение:" name="text1"></textarea>
```